# How to fetch data from an API using express.js

Tags: express

API
(https://api.mosmarts.com/truck/v0/api.php)
The API is scripted in PHP and accepts GET & POST commands and in return it responds  back with a JSON response data.
To retrieve data the API requires “functionality” and “action” among other params as  show below.
Command for retrieving all truck
Command for retrieving all truck
Payloads
{
"functionality" : "get",
"action" : "get_all_truck"
}
Command to retrieving truck inspection details by id
Payloads
{
"functionality" : "get",
"action" : "get_inspection_history",
"truckId" : "1"
}
NB: you will get truckId from command "get_all_truck" above

What’s expected from you

As the software developer you are tasked to design and develop a web-based  backend solution that will have:

1. Dashboard: -
   • Retrieve and indicate total number of trucks
   • Retrieve and indicate number of inspection repairs requested 2. List all Trucks: -
   • Implement search option
2. Inspection List: -
   • Implement filter by truck
   i have  some code using express.js bt i get is a 404 error, no data retrieved.

**app.js**

```
const apiCallFromRequest = require('./Request')
const apiCallFromNode = require('./NodeJsCall')

const http = require('http')

http.createServer((req, res) => {
        if(req.url === "/request"){
            apiCallFromRequest.callApi(function(response){
                //console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                res.write(JSON.stringify(response));
                res.end();
            });
        }
        else if(req.url === "/node"){
            apiCallFromNode.callApi(function(response){
                res.write(response);
                res.end();
            });
        }
        
        // res.end();
}).listen(3000);

console.log("service running on 3000 port....");
```

**NodeJsCall.js**

```
const https = require('https');

_EXTERNAL_URL = 'https://api.mosmarts.com/truck/v0/api.php';


const callExternalApiUsingHttp = (callback) => {
    https.get(_EXTERNAL_URL, (resp) => {
    let data = '';

    // A chunk of data has been recieved.
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
    });

    // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
    resp.on('end', () => {
        return callback(data);
       // console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    });

    }).on("error", (err) => {

    console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });
}

module.exports.callApi = callExternalApiUsingHttp;
```

**Request.js**

```
    const request = require('request');

_EXTERNAL_URL = 'https://api.mosmarts.com/truck/v0/api.php';

const callExternalApiUsingRequest = (callback) => {
    request(_EXTERNAL_URL, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) {
        return callback(err);
     }
    return callback(body);
    });
}

module.exports.callApi = callExternalApiUsingRequest;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey Gerald you can find a simple response for this kind of question on google.

if you are a real beginner I would propose you the Axios npm.
here is an example of a really simple GET request with axios.

```js
axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/mapbox')
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data.created_at);
  });
```